# How should I pass an array by value? Isn't Clone() discouraged?

Tags: c#, arrays, pass-by-value

I've been debugging a C# program of mine, and after several fruitless spans of time, discovered the error came from "accidentally" passing an array by reference instead of by value.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
//1st pass
currentVertices = levels[0].vertices;   
currentVertices[0].Position.Z -= 10;

//2nd pass
currentVertices = levels[1].vertices;
currentVertices[0].Position.Z -= 10;

//3rd pass
currentVertices = levels[0].vertices;
currentVertices[0].Position.Z -= 10;  

//currentVertices[0].Position.Z is now 10 less than expected;
//20 less than it started. Further loops will increase the difference in expected
//value.
```

I was not expecting to have passed the Array by reference, but I accidentally did so anyway.

Is there a way to assign an array by *value* instead of by reference? I know that I could iterate through both arrays, assigning each term individually, but that seems unnecessarily complex. I'm reasonably sure that the Clone() function, well, clones, the values without the respective references, but is that the only way to assign by value? I.e. `currentVertices = levels[1].vertices.Clone();`

Isn't Clone() generally discouraged? What's the best practice for passing arrays by value?

In the short term, I've simply hardcoded what the values should be after being loaded.

[As one of my moderator friends remarked,](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2570775#2570775)

> "I see you solved pass-by-reference through by-pass-reference."

Comment: I see you're trying to pass arrays by value. You should totally drop that and use jQuery.

Comment: "Isn't Clone() generally discouraged?" As far as I've seen, it's generally *recommended*.

Comment: Your understanding of all this seems strangely backwards.

Comment: Might someone explain their downvote? Please let me know what's unclear!

Comment: @Raven Dreamer, I didn't downvote.  One point of un-clarity is: currentVertices[0].Position.Z - 10;   That's an expression.  There's no assignment.  It's unclear how that modifies instances in the array.

Comment: @DavidB in fact, that line *will not compile*.  Raven Dreamer perhaps the down vote was a result of your posting sample code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @phoog Ah, good point. I suppose, in my defense, I do list it as "pseudocode". I'll go adjust it to C# syntax though. (Was missing the '=' part of "-=")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in C# only value types are passed "by value". (This is an oversimplification, but that is a decent way to look at it.)  Every thing else is actually a reference that is passed by value, which is similar to passing a pointer.  (Note that this is different to passing "by ref", which would allow the update of a variable in a calling method.)

You have two options:

1. refactor your code to avoid mutating the objects in the array
2. deep-clone the array

Those are roughly in the order that I would recommend.

Comment: "There is no such thing as passing an array by value in any language." In PHP, all arrays are passed by value by default.

Comment: @BolClock:  I had already removed that, but are you sure that in PHP, an array is copied every time it is passed?

Comment: Well, not every time, only on modification or iteration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Perl passes arrays by value unless you tell it to pass a reference.

Comment: In C++, if you pass a `std::array` object, or in fact any user-defined type with an array member, you'll get a complete shallow copy of the array (pass by value).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to assign an array by value instead of by reference?

No.  variables of reference types (and System.Array is a reference type) reference their instances.

---

It seems to me that you expect the vertices property to give you a deep copy of the array, instead of the original.

Even if you call [Clone, that's a shallow copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx).  Clone does not make copies of the contents of the array.

If you must have a deep copy, I recommend Serialization.  That may be overkill for this particular application.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to have a new array passed to the function, `.Clone()` is the fastest way to do it. In this situation, though, I would typically consider using [`Array.AsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53kysx7b.aspx) instead to give you a `Collection` wrapper around your array.

As MSDN describes in regards to `AsReadOnly`:

> To prevent any modifications to the array, expose the array only through this wrapper.
>
> A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper that prevents modifying the collection; therefore, if changes are made to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those changes.
>
> This method is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Care to give any explanation for AsReadOnly?

Comment: Won't `AsReadOnly` prevent me from incrementing its values at all?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: A read-only collection is an alternative to passing an array by value. I don't know if it will help you, though.

Comment: @RavenDreamer No; AsReadOnly applies to the items of the collection itself: You can't add/remove/change the references stored in the array. It has nothing to do with the *members* of those items.

Comment: AsReadOnly will still give you a reference to the array (and therefore the items in the array).  AsReadOnly only prevents modifications to the array, it does not prevent modifications to the items in the array.  Since you are modifying an item in the array, you'd see the same behavior as before.